# Why is the function $y(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ not a distribution?

Tags: smooth-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Why is this function not a distribution? I am trying to understand how this function is related to the Cauchy Principle Value theorem or how the theorem is able to explain this. A simple explanation is greatly appreciated, thankyou

Comment: A moment, I think I have mixed something. If I remember right, it is a function that is non-zero only in a finite interval.

Comment: I think you are talking about tests functions ($C^\infty$ and compact support), which is the domain of definition of distributions. @Peter

Comment: Maybe the german word "distribution" does not mean the same as the english word "distribution". Seems you mean something else than what I remembered.

Comment: This is highly possible, I think he is referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) BTW. And since I am also not a native english speaker I may be on the wrong track too. @Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defines a distribution iff it is locally integrable, and $\frac 1 x$ is not around $0$. Indeed, you will have trouble defining $\int_{-1}^1 \frac 1 x \phi(x) dx$ for tests function for whose support is a neighbourhood of $0$.

A way to go around the problem is by using [Cauchy's principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), because the integrability only fails at one point, and thus we are able to define a distribution (which formaly is just a linear form from the tests functions to $\mathbb{R}$) in some way from such a function.

EDIT : 
As said before, a distribution is a continuous linear form over the space of test functions $\mathcal{D}$. The non-integrability of $\frac 1 x$ prevent us from using the standard distribution definition from a function $f$, which is $T_f:\phi \mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} f \phi $. Indeed, in this case, such operator is not continuous (you can try to construct a sequence such that $|T_f (\phi_n)| \to \infty$ while $\|\phi_n\|<1$, their support have to be neighbourhood of $0$ of course). However, we can enforce continuity by considering the principal value instead, and this is exactly what is being prooven in the previous link.

Comment: i think i follow the explanation, but im a bit confused on what u mean by ''same sign as 1/x''

Comment: Edited, that was not a good explanation. @curiousboi

Comment: i see, thankyou for clarifying the explanation, but im still unclear on how the cauchy principal is able to define the function as a distribution, a simple, short explanation should suffice if you dont mind elaborating further :) thank you again. @nicomezi

Comment: You are welcome. Added some more details. Tell me if it is enough. @curiousboi